# Как правильно заносить символы в отдельную строку?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Нужно с клавиатуры ввести случайную последовательность нулей и единиц, которая должна быть разбита на несколько частей по 4 символа. Для того, чтобы это реализовать я использовал цикл, который должен повториться N/4 раз. Внутри этого цикла я создал другой цикл, где в сегмент посимвольно заносятся нули и единицы введённой строки. После этого цикла на выходе должно быть несколько последовательностей по 4 символа, но вместо этого выводится пустота.

```
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    cout << "Избыточное кодирование 4B/5B" << endl;
    cout << "Введите количество символов" << endl;
    string old;
    cout << "Введите двоичный код" << endl;
    cin >> old;
    int N=old.size();
string tmp;
            for (int m = 0; m < N / 4; m++)
            {
            for (int i = m*4+1; i < 4(m+1); i++)
            {
                tmp[m] += old[i];
            }
            cout << tmp[m] << endl;
             }
```

Если выводить только одну последовательность, то программа удачно выдаёт на выходе 4 символа, которые и ввели.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        tmp += old[i];
    }
    cout << tmp << endl;
```

Как в первом случае правильно заносить символы в строку с определённым индексом?

Answer (score 0):

Вы как-то непонятно сформулировали свои желания... вы хотите что-то вроде [этого](https://ideone.com/zaQoH1)?

```
cin >> old;
for(int i = 0; i < old.size(); ++i)
{
    cout << old[i];
    if (i%4 == 3) cout << " ";
}
```

Comment: Нет, немного не так. Оказалось, что я просто заполнял строковый массив длиной 1 символ 4 четырьмя символами из первой переменной. В любом случае, спасибо, что уделили внимание моему вопросу

Answer (score 0):

Я уже разобрался решил сделать так

```
cout << "Введите двоичный код" << endl;
    cin >> old;
        int N=old.size();
    
    string fresh;

    string tmp;
    for (int m = 0; m < N / 4; m++)
    {
    for (int i = m*4; i < 4*(m+1); i++)
    {
        tmp += old[i];
    }
cout<<tmp<<endl;
}
```